# Unrecognized selector sent to instance of ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a method in Appdelegate.m

```
- (AppDelegate *)service;
```

Now in ViewController I have included app delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

In ViewController.h I have created property with "weak" reference:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service;
```

And in implementation file ViewController.m:

```
_service = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] service];
```

But it's showing the error,

```
-[AppDelegate service]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a284bc0
2016-10-14 14:21:34.216 PicassaClient[2474:134418] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate service]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a284bc0'
```

Where I am wrong?

Comment: provide the body of service method

Comment: put an exception breakpoint and add the code which cause the app to crash

Comment: Have you declared method on Appdelegate.h file?

Comment: What is the reason for the property `service`? Are you sure that `-service` is a method of AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things to be note hear,

first of all u are calling a method but u are not defined, that is the reason it is crashing.

change like below,

in `Appdelegate.h`

add this

```
- (GDataServiceGooglePhotos *)service; //it returns the type `GDataServiceGooglePhotos`
```

in `Appdelegate.m`

```
- (GDataServiceGooglePhotos *)service 
  {
   //your code 


   //finally
   return myGDataServiceGooglePhotos; // it is the instance of type GDataServiceGooglePhotos
  }
```

In ViewController.h , same as u are doing

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service;
```

in ViewController.m:

```
_service = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] service]; //hear u are calling the method named "service" which is returning  an instance of type "GDataServiceGooglePhotos"
```

Comment: The service property of the view controller is without any meaning to the service method of the app delegate.